# About Buckingham pi theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, dimensional-analysis

Im confused about idea staying behind [Buckingham pi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem). We forcing terms to cancel each other dimensionally and getting some dimensionless number. And what does it give us? Whats significance of it mathematically? It looks so random and without sense we can just add-multiply-substract-divide. PI terms as we want and they are changing. So whats its importance can someone explain?

Comment: Have you read through the examples given in the Wikipedia article you referenced?  I think they answer your question well.

Comment: All you need is a better text explaining Buckingham $\Pi$ and dimensionless groups. Google is your oyster...